# Fetch in node receiving status code 464 but working in browser

Tags: node.js, https, fetch, http-status-codes

I'm a requesting a url with fetch in my node app and the response status is 464 (without responseText and without any error message). But I could't find any info about that.
Also if I request the same url with my browser (Chrome) then it works fine (no need to send any cookies or auth, it works in incognito window too)

What could be causing this?

EDIT: seems to be a problem with AWS Load Balancer, my problem is exactly this:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=964799
But there's no solution in that post, so maybe could be helpful to put it here if someone knows the problem (I'm suspecting is related with HTTP 2.0 but not sure, could it be?)

Response Header in Node is:
Server=awselb/2.0
Content-Length=0
HttpCode=464

But in Chrome:
server: nginx/1.18.0

Comment: can you show how you do a request in a browser and in Node,js?

Comment: @Anatoly i have added more info

Comment: I can confirm is a HTTP 2.0 thing, and I'm pretty sure the problem if from node-fetch package. The weird thing was the response from AWS with that non official 464 status

Comment: Can you try `got` or `axios` instead of `fetch`?

Comment: at least from here it seems to be a problem for almost all http libraries in node: https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#comparison

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue just today. My target group was configured for HTTP/2, but, the backend service was not prepared for that traffic. So, when I rebuilt the target group using HTTP/1.1, traffic began to function as expected.

When creating a target group, the options presented to me for HTTP protocol options were (as shown in the AWS Console):

> ## HTTP/1.1
>
> Send requests to targets using HTTP/1.1. Supported when the request
> protocol is HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.
>
> ## HTTP/2
>
> Send requests to targets using HTTP/2. Supported when the request
> protocol is HTTP/2 or gRPC, but gRPC-specific features are not
> available.