# I am not able to clone repository from GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I am trying to clone the repo from GitLab, I am getting the below issue :

```
Cloning into 'path'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/shared/<my repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 464
```

I tried adding windows credentials manually into "Windows credentials" in the control panel, but it did not work, and getting the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the rights to clone this repo on this `https://gitlab.com/shared/.git/` ?

Comment: Yes, I cross-checked about the permission, I have the access to clone it.

Comment: 464 indicates a load balancer error. See [Fetch in node receiving status code 464 but working in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65233710/1256452). This doesn't have anything to do with Git itself, but could be caused by some middleware box between you and the GitLab server.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the URL address you are inputting.

To clone a repo, go to the repo page and choose blue `Clone` button to the right:

[image]

Then you can choose whether you want to clone via SSH or HTTPS. Since you had problem with URL, you want to choose `HTTPS` one. Simply click on the *clipboard* icon and paste it to

`git clone URL`

You should be good to go.

Comment: I am following the same step you mentioned, for cloning. With the same URL, my other teammates are able to clone the repo and also I am having all the permission for GitLab.